# Why no warning for GetHashCode() without Equals()

Tags: c#

I apologize for the shortness of the title, but the actual title would be a bit too long. Here is the actual long title:

#### Why a warning when overriding `Equals()` without `GetHashCode()` but no warning when overriding `GetHashCode()` without `Equals()`?

I also apologize in advance about the fact that this is not a "What is the X of Y" type of question, it is more of an "I observed X; am I missing something?" type of question.

So, consider the following:

```
class A
{
    public override bool Equals( object other ) => true; //warning CS0659
}

class B
{
    public override int GetHashCode() => 42; //No warning
}
```

I am aware of the reasons behind warning CS0659 "class overrides Object.Equals(object o) but does not override Object.GetHashCode()". I do not agree with those reasons, because `Equals()` is perfectly viable for a mutable class, whereas such a class must of course never be used as a key in a hash map, and therefore must not have a `GetHashCode()`, but my objections are irrelevant, and in any case, receiving a warning which you have no need for is never a problem, because you can always disable it.

It is, however, a problem when you can think of a warning that you would have a use for, but you are not receiving such a warning.

This is what `class B` above demonstrates.  Overriding `GetHashCode()` without also overriding `Equals()` is almost certainly a grave mistake, and yet there is no warning. Not by the C# compiler, nor by ReSharper.

Does anyone know why?

Is there something I am missing?

Could it be that the warning exists, but I must know some configuration magic to tease it out of the compiler?

Could it be that I must declare my class in some weird way like `public` `sealed` `albino` or something?

Are there any legitimate reasons for the absence of the warning?

**EDIT**

So far there have been a few answers to this question and they all pretty much state the same thing: there is no warning because there is no violation of the contract for `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()`.

Ladies and gentlemen, you are missing the point.

(Or maybe I should say I apologize for failing to make the point more clear.)

The "no violation of contract" argument in support of the absence of this warning makes about as much sense as trying to support the absence of some other warning, like "event is never used", on the grounds that by declaring an event and never using it you are not violating any contract either.

Well, first of all, if I was violating some contract by declaring an event and never using it, I would expect an error, not a warning.

But most importantly, declaring an event and never using it is a grave and insidious mistake, so it needs a warning, ***regardless of contracts***.

#### And in fact, there is a warning for it!

It is CS0067 "The event '{0}' is never used".

See? warnings do not require any contracts to be violated.

So that argument is blown out of the water.

Any other arguments, please?

Comment: Returning a constant from `GetHashCode` and not overriding `Equals` is actually functionally alright because it does not return different hash codes for equal instances. It's just highly ineffective as it degrades the lookup performance of all hash based collections to O(n).

Comment: _'...is almost certainly a grave mistake'_ - your example still sticks to the contract, however.

Comment: I think is because `GetHashCode` must be dependable of `Equals`, not the other way around, so when you change the `Equals` logic you should also change the `GetHashCode`, but you can change the `GetHashCode` implementation without changing `Equals` logic, as long as `GetHashCode` still follows `Equals`rules.

Comment: In case anyone didn't get the reference to `42` https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/42/

Comment: Ah, where are the good old days when Eric Lippert himself would show up and answer questions of this kind...  (-:=

Answer (score 5):

The [GetHashCode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.8) method should reflect the `Equals` logic; the rules are:

- if two things are equal (`Equals(...) == true`) then they must return the same value for `GetHashCode()`
- if the `GetHashCode()` is equal, it is not necessary for them to be the same; this is a collision, and `Equals` will be called to see if it is a real equality or not.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of all that, but it does not answer the question. A warning when overriding `Equals()` without `GetHashCode()` warns against a ***possible*** violation of a contract, while the contract ***might*** be intended to be honored;  a warning when overriding `GetHashCode()` without `Equals()` would be warning against ***a very possible*** violation of a contract which is ***certainly*** intended to be honored.  (A class does not implement `GetHashCode()` unless it intends to act as a key in a hash map.)

Answer (score 2):

When you override **only** the `GetHashCode()` method, nothing gets broken or violated (in terms of the `Equals()`/`GetHashCode()` contract). The `Equals()` method still returns `true` iff it is the same object and will return `false` for every other object. There is no way to break the contract when you override **only** the `GetHashCode()` method.

- Two references to the exact same object will return the same `GetHashCode()` since it is in fact the same object and the state of the object hasn't changed in the meantime, as required by the contract of `GetHashCode()`. (are `Equals()` => same `GetHashCode()`)
- Additionally, when two hash codes are different that means that the two objects must not be `Equals()` to each other. But since two different objects are never `Equals()` anyway (when not overridden) this requirement is automatically fulfilled. (different `GetHashCode()` => not `Equals()`)

As you don't break any contracts, you will not get any warning (unlike [warning CS0659](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0659) as you mentioned) by the compiler. It is not required that you need to override the `Equals()` method in such a case.